# How can I get each selected radio input to retain its border?

Tags: jquery

I have this bit of jquery that add a .selected class to a radio button's label when its been selected.

But I'd like this to work on each group of radio buttons

HTML:

## Group 1

Credit / Debit Card

```
<div class="radio radio--inline">
    <label for="offline">
        <input type="radio" name="payment-option" id="offline" value="offline"> Offline Payments
    </label>
</div>

<h1>Group 2</h1>
<div class="radio radio--inline">
    <label for="credit-card1">
        <input type="radio" name="payment-option2" id="credit-card1" value="credit-card"> Credit / Debit Card
    </label>
</div>

<div class="radio radio--inline">
    <label for="offline1">
        <input type="radio" name="payment-option2" id="offline1" value="offline"> Offline Payments
    </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.selected {
  border: 2px solid purple;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
 var $radioButtons = $('.radio input[type="radio"]');
  $radioButtons.click(function() {
   $('label').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).closest('label').addClass('selected');
 });
});
```

See: http://jsbin.com/biciku/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are removing `.selected` form all `label`s.

change this

<strike>$('label').removeClass('selected');</strike>

to

```
   $('.radio input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').parent('label').removeClass('selected');
```

Full code:

```
$(function() {
  var $radioButtons = $('.radio input[type="radio"]');
  $radioButtons.click(function() {

    $('.radio input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').parent('label').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).closest('label').addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

Check this: http://jsbin.com/sogejecodi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Just check them all each time:

```
$radioButtons.click(function() {
  $("label").each(
    function(){
       var $t = $(this);
       $t[$("#" + $t.prop('for') + ':checked').length > 0 ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('selected');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This becomes cleaner and easier if you change your HTML to match the structure of the information.

updated jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/ruhamuquyo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

I wrapped each fieldset in `<fieldset>` and made some other minor improvements such as changing the click listener to change, and adding transparent border around non-selected labels to prevent jitter on border change.